# regexp to find all lines without a number pattern exept a specific number

Tags: regex, grep

I have some experience in regexp and grep command but couldn't find a way to do the following.

Lets immagine I have following text file:

```
abc 123 cdf
aze ert
vfg 12 gj
zrr 345 rty
top flg 567
aze 345 odi
```

I need to get all lines containing '345' and lines without other number matching the patern [0-9]{3} so it would return:

```
aze ert
vfg 12 gj
zrr 345 rty
aze 345 odi
```

Regards,
X

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below.

```
grep -P '\b345\b|^(?!.*\b\d{3}\b)' file
```

`\b345\b` matches the line which contains the number 345 at very first.

`(?!.*\b\d{3}\b)` negative lookahead asserts that the line we are going to match won't contain a three digit number. If yes then it would match the start of that particular line. `-P` alone will print all the lines which has a match.

Answer (score 1):

You need a negative look ahead, which grep supports if you use the `-P` (perl) option:

```
grep -P "\b345\b|^(?!.*\b[0-9]{3}\b)"
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/7PYA0Axva6)

Comment: @avin as it happens yes, but I posted before seeing your post (my browser crashed a couple of times)

Comment: @avin if you must know I am on an iPhone, and it's pretty slow going

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*?345.*$|^(?!(?:.*\d){3,}).*$
```

Try this with `grep -P`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/4

Answer (score 0):

Great thank you all !! never heard before about negative lookahead.

So, to explain further and give more simple regexp:

grep -P '345|^(?!.*[0-9]{3})' file

-P is to use perl style regexp (supporting the lookahead)
?! is the negative lookahead expression

Thanks.

Comment: @xtrder99 [accept the answer which helps you  to get the working solution at very first.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)